# Does it matter in which space the Stones are placed?

Tags: marvel, comics, infinity-stones

In *Avengers: Infinity War*

> Thanos gathers the Infinity Stones one at a time.

I realize the MCU and comics are different but **in the comics** is it important which Stone goes in which slot and the order they are placed there?

Comment: Given that he seemed to place them all in some kind of order(1,2,3,4 on his knuckles, 5 on his thumb, 6 on the back of his palm) as he got them I'm guessing not as the chance they all aligned up like that seems slim

Comment: MCU question: [Is there a specific order to the Infinity Stones?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186868/13024)

Comment: This question specifically stated in the comics the post listed as the duplicate is specifically about the MCU

Answer (score 2):

In the MCU I would argue that the order doesn't appear to matter but in the comics things are a bit different. In Earth-616 and the comic *New Avengers Volume 3 Issue 3* the Gems get placed in an order different to how they were being held but were being "forced into one" to create the Gauntlet. It is unclear if they switch positions because they need to be in a certain position or just because that's how they ended up or because that's how the group wanted them to appear.

[image: The Avengers gather to form the Gauntlet] [image: The Avengers form the Gauntlet]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

In the *Infinity Gauntlet* Thanos seems to place the Gems into the Gauntlet in a similar manner to how he did it in *Avengers: Infinity War* which would indicate to me that the order doesn't matter. He gets them one at a time from defeating the original keepers.

> Not even Death realized what *Limitless might* the Mad Titan was striving for. Through cunning, sheer strength, and murder, Thanos wrested the *Infinity Gems* from those that possessed them and with each acquisition he gained *mastery* over...

[image: Thanos gains all the Infinity Gems]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

It's worth noting that in each 3 instances here, the two comics plus the MCU, [the order of the Infinity Stones is different](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/187684/58193) which could be something to do with the different universe or could indicate that the order doesn't actually matter.